# I'm confused about the type of function `foldr` in haskell

Tags: haskell

In the book "Programming in Haskell", the definition of foldr is:

```
foldr :: (a -> b ->b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr f v [] = v
foldr f v (x:xs) = f x (foldr f v xs)
```

I can't understand `f` very well.

Cause `f` is applied to `[a]`, the argument `a` in `(a -> b -> b)` is obvious.
The argument `v` has type `b`, but the last `b` in (a -> b -> **b**) and (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> **b** is weird.

Does it mean the results of functions `f` and `foldr` have type `b`? How could that be possible?

Comment: I started to write an answer to the "How could that be possible?" part of the question, but then got stuck a bit. Can you say why you think it should be impossible? That would help guide explanations, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foldr f v` maps the list

```
x1 : x2 : ... : []
-- i.e., in prefix notation
(:) x1 ((:) x2 (...  []))
```

into the value

```
f x1 (f x2 (... v))
```

Informally, it "replaces" (or "interprets") the `(:)` constructor with `f`, and the `[]` constructor with `v`.

From the formula above, we can see that the result of `f` is used (many times) as the second argument of `f`. Hence they must have the same type (`b`, in your question). The final result of `foldr` is the result of the outermost `f`, hence it is the same `b` as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you admit `v` has type `b`, then the result of the `foldr` *has* to have type `b`, because `v` is a possible result of `foldr`:

```
foldr f v [] = v
```

And then since the result of `foldr` has to be `b`, then the result of `f` has to be `b` as well, since an `f` result is a possible `foldr` result:

```
-- f and foldr have to return the same type!
foldr f v (x:xs) = f x (foldr f v xs)
```